# Error TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the values that accomplish two conditions in one dataframe to include it in another dataframe but I'm getting an error

```
for index, row in data_orders_2_sample.iterrows():

    row['potential_couriers'] = ((data_courier_cash_balance_2_sample[data_courier_cash_balance_2_sample.acum_amount_eu >= 
                                                                                    row['purchase_price']]) 
                                 & (data_courier_cash_balance_2_sample.created_day == row['assignment_time'])
                                ).count()['courier_id']
    data_orders_2_sample.at[index,'potential_couriers'] = row['potential_couriers']

data_orders_2_sample.head()
```

the error is

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

The thing is that if I comment one of the two conditions the code goes fine, so the error is in the & but I don't know how to solve it. Any help, please?

Thank you all :)

Comment: Can you give an example of the input data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do something like this:

```
df =data_orders_2_sample
df['potential_couriers'] = df[
    (df.acum_amount_eu >= df.purchase_price) & (df.created_day == df.assignment_time)
].count()['courier_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I've found another workaround using numpy

```
import numpy as np

for index, row in data_orders_2.iterrows():

    row['potential_couriers'] = np.sum(((data_courier_cash_balance_2.acum_amount_eu) >= 
    row.purchase_price) & 
    (data_courier_cash_balance_2.created_day == 
    row.assignment_time))
    data_orders_2.at[index,'potential_couriers'] = row['potential_couriers']

data_orders_2
```